# Multiple Laravel setups on same server

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I have an Ubuntu Server based webserver with the most current version of Apache and PHP.
I have two subdomains, let's call them: a.x.com and b.x.com, pointing to the same server. I use virtual hosts for domain configuration. This works just fine. It could be important that x.com uses wildcard SSL, so I have a common certificate for my domains.

On a.x.com I installed Laravel and made a small site. That's ok.

On b.x.com I also wanted to install a separate Laravel but I ran into a problem. When I type b.x.com in my browser I see exactly the same as I see under a.x.com except the static objects like images. I've tried echoing the application variables in Laravel and even the __DIR__ variable contains the path of a.x.com.

I spent two days trying to find a solution and I think there's only one line in Laravel I should change.

Have you seen this problem before?

Abel

Comment: This has very little to do with Laravel and is really a server / apache configuration question. You need to setup different `DocumentRoot`'s for each of the subdomains.

Comment: This is the VirtualHost setup: http://pastebin.com/PewgWSKC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. I was running Apache 2.4 and php 5.5 and the problem went away when I removed Xcache.

```
apt-get remove php5-xcache
```

Comment: Wow. This was it. Thanks! Although I don't think you actually need to uninstall it. I just did `php5dismod xcache`

Comment: xcache was the problem for us also. Uninstalling it solved the problem. The behavior was really weird when xcache was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to group your routes by prefix ?

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'a'), function()
{
    //Routes for a.x.com
});


Route::group(array('prefix' => 'b'), function()
{
    //Routes for b.x.com
});
```

Comment: These are two different setups of Laravel. It seems like they have a common storage something. If I restart Apache and load a.x.com first b.x.com will show exactly the same as a.x.com. If I restart Apache and load b.x.com first, then a.x.com will be exactly the same as b.x.com. Weird.